# Is it possible to bind the property of a datacontext to the property of another datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a Class which I use in a control for defining colors :

```
public class ColorModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Color Color{ get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

I also have a class which I wish to use for defining two-color LinearGradient Brushes :

```
public class GradientModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Color First{ get { ... } set { ... } }
    public Color Last{ get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

Both of these classes serve as DataContexts for the controls that are responsible for defining their respective values.

I want to be able to use the ColorModel that I have defined to dictate the value of the First and Last colors of the GradientModel ( using two separate controls, each housing a ColorModel as a DataContext ).

I'm endeavoring to adhere to the MVVM as closely as possible.

How can I go about accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to accomplish this could be to define your `GradientModel` as follows:

```
public class GradientModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public ColorModel First{ get { ... } set { ... } }
    public ColorModel Last{ get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

That is, instead of defining the properties as `Color`, define them as `ColorModel`. Then in the constructor, subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event and update your members accordingly.

Note: You'll have to update your binding paths from `First` to `First.Color` and so on.

Comment: Have to say I agree with this approach. The WPF binding engine is designed to facilitate loose binding between view and view model. The question concerns binding between view models, so at the very least you want something that is capable of running independent of the view and compatible with unit testing etc. Just because something initially appears convenient doesn't mean it's the right technology for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Is there any reason to assign a setter to the `ColorModel` properties? I ask this because within the model will need to be defined the `ColorModel` object which I will then furnish as the `DataContext` for the control responsible for it.

Comment: This did  the trick. This was about what I was thinking but I wasn't 100% sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

> ColorModel that I have defined to dictate the value of the First and Last colors of the GradientModel

Within `ColorModel` instance, subscribe to the instance of `GradientModel`'s `INotifyPropertyChanged` mechanism. Then within the subscription operation method just detect the property `Color` change event and when it occurs extract its value and update the properties of `First` and `Last` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. By rule, `Binding` will work only on `DependencyProperty` of `DependencyObject`.
2. Make `ColorModel`, and `GradientModel` `DependencyObject`.
3. Create a `MainViewModel` so that you can set up a `Binding`.

   ```
   public class MainViewModel
   {
       public ColorModel CM1 { get; set; }
       public ColorModel CM2 { get; set; }

       public GradientModel GM { get; set; }

       public MainViewModel()
       {
           CM1 = new ColorModel();
           CM2 = new ColorModel();
           GM = new GradientModel();

           Binding b1 = new Binding("Color");
           b1.Source = CM1;
           b1.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
           BindingOperations.SetBinding(GM, GradientModel.FirstProperty, b1);

           Binding b2 = new Binding("Color");
           b2.Source = CM2;
           b2.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
           BindingOperations.SetBinding(GM, GradientModel.LastProperty, b2);
       }
   }

   <TextBox x:Name="Ctrl1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="32,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CM1.Color}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
   <TextBox x:Name="Ctrl2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="32,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CM2.Color}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
   ```

XAML ( I have used string type instead of Color type in your VMs for demo. )

```
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="210,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding GM.First}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="#FFE8D7D7"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="352,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding GM.Last}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="#FFECD7D7"/>
```